# R sum of random numbers?

Tags: arrays, r, math

I am trying to Write a R function that will generate n(that are passed to a function) random numbers and return the sum of the numbers and show that random set of numbers

I am new to R and assuming an array would be used here,but not sure. 
Also, my attempt only allows for 10 numbers, but if i try to do it for any amount other than 10 it gives wrong sum.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but this is what i have got so far.

```
random.sum <- function(n) {  
x[1:n] <- ceiling(10*runif(n)) 
cat("x:", x[1:n], "\n") 
return(sum(x)) 
}
x <- rep(100, 10)
show(random.sum(10))
```

Comment: I would use a list - `s <- runif(n); list(show = s, sum = sum(s))` - or something similar.

Comment: Don't change your question. If one of the answers provided answers your question you should accept it (by pressing the grey tick next to the voting arrows). Then, if you have a new question you should ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct.

You don't need to assign `x` to anything outside the function, and inside your function you don't need to subset `x`, you can just assign it with the `n` random numbers. Then it will work

```
random.sum <- function(n) {
    x <- ceiling(10*runif(n)) 
    cat("x:", x, "\n")
    return(sum(x))
    }

random.sum(13)
x: 4 6 10 4 6 10 8 2 5 10 4 4 6 
[1] 79
```

---

#### Explanation

If you assign `x <- rep(100, 10)` outside the function, you are creating a vector size 10, each element being value 100.

Due to 'lexical scoping', this `x` is available inside the `random.sum` function, so when you have the line

```
x[1:4] <- ceiling(10*runif(n))   ## where n = 4
```

You are assigning the first 4 values of `x` to be a random number, but the remaining values are still 100. So your sum is actually `(100 * 6) + 4 random numbers`

You can see this happening if you throw in a few `print` statements into your original function

```
random.sum <- function(n) {
    print(x)
    x[1:n] <- ceiling(10*runif(n)) 
    print(x)
    cat("x:", x[1:n], "\n")
    print(x)
    return(sum(x))
} 

x <- rep(100, 10)
random.sum(4)

# [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
# [1]   5   2   1   3 100 100 100 100 100 100
# x: 5 2 1 3 
# [1]   5   2   1   3 100 100 100 100 100 100
# [1] 611
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
random.sum <- function(n) {
  # Store n random integers between 0 and 100 in vector called random_nums
  random_nums <- floor(runif(n, min=0, max=100))

  # Show the random numbers
  print(random_nums)

  # Return the sum of the random numbers
  return(sum(random_nums))
}

print(paste("Sum:", random.sum(5), sep=" "))
```

**Example Output**

```
[1] 57  3 64 18 46
[1] "Sum: 188"
```